# Pooling samples -- what are the effects

Tags: modeling, experiment-design, pooling

There is an experiment in which biological samples are taken for several treatments and a control. For each treatment, we have enough resources to evaluate 5 samples.

Some researchers suggest (for technical reasons) that for each treatment, we should collect ten samples and pool them, such that we have five pools, each consisting of two biological samples mixed together.

My main interest is in understanding the treatment effect size in the context of biological variability between the samples, which I think will be lost (or complex to analyse) if each pool will be an average of two biological samples (there are also other reasons for not pooling, mostly due to the fact that the pools will be incompatible with other samples and measurements which are not to be pooled). However, the possibility exists that due to technical reasons we will be forced to pool.

**My questions:**

1. Can we estimate the underlying biological variance from the variance of the pools? I think that since we the expected variance of the pools will be $\frac{\sigma^2}{2}$ (given that real the biological variance in the population $\sigma^2$), could we multiply the variance estimate from the pools by $2$ to get the estimate of the biological variance, correct?
2. The experimental design is actually a bit more complex and it's analysis will involve modelling group and random effects (a mixed effect model). The main question will be to understand the treatment effects in the context of the population (and not of the pools). Is it possible to incorporate the pooling into the model?

To elaborate on the second question, I will give a specific example of a model. Consider a randomized block design as follows (I do hope I get it right...):

$Y_{ij}=\beta_0 + \beta_j\cdot T_j + \eta_i\cdot G_i +  \epsilon_{ij} $

in which there is a fixed effect of the treatment ($\beta_j$) and a random effect of the experimental batch ($\eta_i$). I would analyse it using the `nlme` or `lmer` libraries from R, applying mixed effect models. But I am confused as to what I would have to do if the samples were pooled.